# Cannot add multiple css files in html page layout

Tags: 2013, css, page-layout

I need to include multiple css files in one HTML Page Layout - a webfont, bootstrap, and my own custom styles.  The only thing that loads is my custom styles -- I can tell from checking the sources in Chrome Dev Tools.  The url pathways are correct.  Additionally, I have the corresponding script files loaded underneath it [jquery, popper, and bootstrap] in simple `<script>` tags. All three of those files load fine.

I have placed my css links after 'AdditionalPageHead' in the html page layout.  Has anyone else ever encountered this?  I do not understand why it loads my custom styles, and bypasses everything else.  I'm using 2013 OnPrem.

My css-links look like this:

`<link href="\path\bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

`<link href="\path\fontawesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

`<link href="\path\style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Answer (score 1):

Try below solutions:

**Solution 1**:

If your page layout is an HTML file, try this:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Test/Custom.css %&#62;" runat="server" after="corev15.css"/>-->
```

If it'is an .aspx file, try this:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Test/Custom.css %&#62;" runat="server" after="corev15.css"/>
```

**Solution 2**:

First, you need to find the following lines of code in the head of the Page Layout's HTML page:

```
<!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
<!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="Publishing" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
```

After those three lines you are free to add `<link>` tags, with the following caveat: use the `ms-design-css-conversion="no"` attribute within the `<link>` tag to "exclude the style sheet from theming".

In the end, you should have a `<link>` tag that looks as follows:

```
<link href="MyPageLayout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ms-design-css-conversion="no" />
```

[Where to add styles in page layouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822368.aspx#WhereStyles)

Comment: Thanks for this, but I researched before posting and was aware of all of those things.  Placing ms-design-conversion gives me an error message that says my css file cannot be read.